# Deploying Kotlin Spring Boot Application Via WebSphere

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, websphere

I've written a Spring Boot microservice in Kotlin using IntelliJ Idea where it runs fine locally. I need to deploy it via WebShpere but am having problems launching the WAR there.

The main class of the microservice is as follows

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```

After creating the WAR using `mvn clean install`, if I deploy it via WebSphere with just this class the `SystemOut.log` file shows that the service doesn't launch at all.  There is no log entry reading `"Started MyApplication in... <seconds>"`

Another developer added the following class to the same package:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

class ServletInitializer : SpringBootServletInitializer() {

    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder) : SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return application.sources(MyApplication::class.java)
    }

}
```

If I rebuild using Maven and redeploy via WebShpere, the SystemOut.log file shows that service starts to launch but instead of running the MyApplication class the log simply reads `"Started ServletInitializer in... <seconds>"`

I can't understand why WebSphere doesn't seem to launch or recognise the main class.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: If you deploy to web sphere it will not run the `main` it will execute the `ServletInitializer` which will use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to bootstrap the application.

Comment: "If you deploy to web sphere it will not run the `main`"  -- why is that?  And if it uses the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to bootstrap the application does that mean the application is then running successfully?

Comment: It should run successfully. It doesn't execute the main because it isn't a command line application but a web application.